# drupal 7 views not displaying anything

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

The following code doesn't give any error but my view isn't displaying anything. Can someone give me a hint?

```
$view = views_get_view('featured_articles');
$view->set_display('block');
$view->set_arguments($node->nid);
$view->execute();
print $view->render();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
$view->set_arguments($node->nid);
```

To

```
$view->set_arguments(array($node->nid));
```

Comment: might also want to consider $view->pre_execute();